What does "we are out"mean here?
How much sauce do we still have?
We are out
What does "out" mean in this sentence?

You need to tell us where you get these phrases from. And and at some point you should show your research e.g. the dictionary definition of "out" even if the definition(s) you read do not fit, we can at least understand why you are asking the question.

It would mean "we are out of sauce".
Literally you are "out" of (no longer in) the state or the situation of having sauce
Basically the same thing as saying "we are without sauce" which is correct english but sounds very formal/serious/dramatic/slightly archaic.
You would see that sentence structure in the context of something more grave such as "we are without hope".
I have no actual proof for this but to me (an australian) saying "we are out" of a consumable such as sauce sounds American.
We would however say "we are out of the woods" and things that you are physically within or without.

Huh - so how would an Australian most likely convey the same information? I had assumed it was universal.

@MarkFoskey Australian here - I agree that it does sound kind of American, though we would still say "we're outta sauce" on occasion.  "There's no sauce" or "we don't have any sauce" would probably be a more common equivalent phrase.

@MarkFoskey: Not an Australian but I do live there. I suspect Esco meant "we are out" (omitting what you are out of), as opposed to "we are out of sauce". I don't hear the former living in Australia (and it sounds American to my ears as well), but I've heard the latter used plenty in Australia as well.

To repeat what Esco said, "we are out", in this context, is short for "we are out of sauce." But I want to add what "we are out of sauce" tells you a bit more than "we have no sauce." It means that they normally have sauce, but they have served it all. That is, they have run out. The next day they will probably have more. Just saying "we have no sauce" doesn't carry the same implication that they did have it earlier, but it's all gone now.
An American would say their car is "out of gas" if their fuel tank is empty. I don't know whether people in the rest of the English-speaking world say "out of petrol" in the same way, but I would have assumed so.

"Out of petrol" is good in the UK.

Is it? Now you have to wait for hours until the AA shows up and gets you going again

It means that there is none. In this case "out" is used in the sense of being gone.

We might use a word before 'out', such as 'all', 'completely', 'totally', etc, perhaps to emphasise that we have run out of something important - we're all out of sauce.

Another way of saying "we are out" would be "we have run out" (link goes to Cambridge English dictionary). In my country (Australia), this is how we would say it.
